# Cookie Based Forms Authentication is Not Working when the website is in an iFrame

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-cookies, forms-authentication

I have developed a Windows Forms Application in C# and **It's perfectly working**. Recently, my client raised a requirement that is, he wants to load **this website inside an iframe of another website**.
So, I created a simple HTML application with a iframe to test this scenario.
While testing, I have identified some properties were not set in the process of ticket building of Forms Authentication. Does anyone know what is the issue here?

This is the way I set cookie,

```
var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userId, chkRememberMe.Checked);
var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

var newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration,
                    ticket.IsPersistent, "insured", ticket.CookiePath);
var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);

cookie.Value = encTicket;
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Here is the properties of the Page.User.Identity object,

```
AuthenticationType = ""
IsAuthenticated = false
Name = ""
Ticket object is not available
```

Web.config

```
<system.web>
<sessionState cookieSameSite="None" timeout="20"/>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>

<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="Login.aspx">
  </forms>
</authentication>
.
.
</system.web>
```

Comment: Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: @OguzOzgul This is regarding to avoid clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites. In my case I want to provide facility to load my website inside an iframe. the issue here is cookie based forms authentication is not working when the login page is called from an iFrame.

Comment: To allow cookies when a cross-domain site is displayed in an iframe, it should provide a p3p header. You are right about the first link, it is for cross-domain js invocation. In the developer tools console, you should see an error, and when you create and send back a valid p3p header from your web app, it should go away. Can you give it a try?

Comment: Thanks mate! I just tried with p3p as a custom header but didn't work. btw, I have used a alternative solution for this issue by using a session variable. Still I'm looking for a ideal solution to continue with "Forms Authentication".